# Order ggplot barchart by numerical data on x axis, not alphabetical on y axis

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to order the data in my ggplot geom_bar chart by the x axis, which are integer values (Crude.Rate = number of deaths per disease), however, the y axis, US states, is keeping the data in alphabetical order. I've tried to create factors of the x axis numerical data, but the chart stays in alphabetical order, with the x axis labels just moved around to match the y axis.

Code:

```
stDis10 <- cdcData %>%
  filter(Year == "2010", ICD.Chapter == "Heart Attack") %>%
  arrange(desc(Crude.Rate)) %>%
  select(State, ICD.Chapter, Crude.Rate)

stDis10$Crude.Rate <- factor(stDis10$Crude.Rate, levels = stDis10$Crude.Rate)

ggplot(stDis10, aes(y = Crude.Rate, x = State)) + geom_bar( stat='identity') + coord_flip()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to change Crude.Rate to a factor. You can reorder State by Crude.Rate:

```
ggplot(stDis10, aes(y = Crude.Rate, x = reorder(State, Crude.Rate))) + geom_col() + coord_flip()
```

(In the latest version of ggplot2, `geom_col()` can be used instead of `geom_bar(stat = "identity")`.)